# Different behaviour of Ctrl-D (Unix) and Ctrl-Z (Windows)

Tags: c, windows, unix, stdin

As per title I am trying to understand the exact behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in a while loop with a gets (which I am required to use). The code I am testing is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char str[80];

    while(printf("Insert string: ") && gets(str) != NULL) {

        puts(str);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If my input is simply a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on Windows) `gets` returns NULL and the program exits correctly. The unclear situation is when I insert something like `house^D^D` (Unix) or `house^Z^Z\n` (Windows).

1. In the first case my interpretation is a `getchar` (or something similar inside the `gets` function) waits for read() to get the input, the first <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> flushes the buffer which is not empty (hence not EOF) then the second time read() is called EOF is triggered.
2. In the second case though, I noticed that the first <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is inserted into the buffer while everything that follows is simply ignored. Hence my understanding is the first read() call inserted `house^Z` and discarded everything else returning 5 (number of characters read). (I say 5 because otherwise I think a simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> should return 1 without triggering EOF). Then the program waits for more input from the user, hence a second read() call.

I'd like to know what I get right and wrong of the way it works and which part of it is simply implementation dependent, if any.

---

Furthermore I noticed that in both Unix and Windows even after EOF is triggered it seem to reset to false in the following `gets()` call and I don't understand why this happens and in which line of the code.

I would really appreciate any kind of help.

---

(12/20/2016) I heavily edited my question in order to avoid confusion

Comment: this expression: `|| !feof(stdin))` has no useful effect.  Mostly because the function: `feof()` checks if the code tried to read past EOF,  And this expression is only checked if EOF was encountered, so will always be false.  Since that function does NOT do what is (usually) expected, strongly suggest never using it.

Comment: this expression: `*curr++` can/will be a problem.  The problem is because of the precedence of the operators in C.  Suggest: `*curr = (char)c;   curr++;`

Comment: I used !feof(stdin) to check if I encountered a reading error instead of eof.  I just tried to emulate the gets(...) function in order to better isolate the source of my doubt (which is getchar())

Comment: if there was a I/O error, the function: `feof()` will not tell you of that error.  Instead:  `#include <errno.h>`  then just before the call to `getchar()` `errno = 0;`  then immediately after the call to `getchar()`  `if( 0 != errno ) // handle error`

Comment: Again, I don't plan on using the function I wrote, but my intuition is that getchar() returns EOF either in case of error or in case of actual EOf. Then if feof() returns false an error has occurred.

Comment: Forget your intuition.  Read the man page for `getchar()` and the man page for `errno`

Comment: Well both cppreference and cplusplus confirm what I knew about the function and the Kernighan Ritchie does seem to further confirm it. But I agree I know nothing about error handling, hence I did not intend to write a perfect function from that point of view. It is just a placeholder for gets (which I know is not a recommended function). Anyway I think we are going off topic.

Comment: Not only is `gets()` not recommended, in the latest C standard it does not even exist.  Strongly suggest using: `fgets()`   You might want to read: <stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong> for further details  and please remember that `C` and `C++` are two different languages, so should be looking at references for the C language when writing in C

Comment: On most modern compilers targeting Windows, the `_WIN32` macro is predefined. You can use that to conditionally include `if (c != 0x1a)` before the `*curr++ = c;` line. That will avoid storing the `^Z` in the input buffer and will wait for more input, similar to how the Unix terminal driver doesn't pass `^D` to `stdin` in `house^D`. Other than that, your function looks to be about right.

Comment: If you don't want to go the macro route, use `if (is_windows() && c != 0x1a)`, where `is_windows()` is a function that tries to detect Windows in some other way. For example, `fopen("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "rb")` would attempt to open the Command Prompt EXE file for reading in binary mode. If `fopen()` returns non-`NULL`, then you are on Windows and need to handle `^Z` specially. A much cheaper method might be to `return getenv("SYSTEMROOT") != NULL`, but there's no guarantee that another environment won't define the `SYSTEMROOT` environment variable, which makes it fragile.

Comment: @Chrono Thank you for the advice. In fact, I don't plan on using the function, I'm a student and I am just trying to understand how getchar() works in Windows vs Unix environment but any advice is very welcome. As far as you know is the behaviour I described (especially the one on Windows) correct and reliable?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell, it's correct. Actually, you can probably still use the `gets()` function, so why not try it out and compare your version to the one provided by the system? There are only three cases to consider--error, `^D`/`^Z\n`, and `input^D^D`/`input^Z\n^Z\n`.

Comment: @Elanigiro I believe that `Ctrl+D` is EOF and `Ctrl+Z` is suspend.

Comment: @MarkYisri `C-z` on Windows is the rough equivalent of `C-d` on Unix and Unix-like systems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The CTRL-D and CTRL-Z "end of file" indicators serve a similar purpose on Unix and Windows systems respectively, but are implemented quite differently.

On Unix systems (including Unix clones like Linux) CTRL-D, while officially described as the end-of-file character, is actually a delimiter character. It does almost the same thing as the end-of-line character (usually carriage return or CTRL-M) which is used to delimit lines. Both characters tell the operating system that the input line is finished and to make it available the program. The only difference is that with end-of-line character a line feed (CTRL-J) character is inserted at the end of the input buffer to mark the end of the line, while with the end-of-file character nothing is inserted.

This means when you enter `house^D^D` on Unix the `read` system call will first return a buffer of length 5 with the 5 characters `house` in it.  When `read` is called again to obtain more input, it will then returns of a buffer of length 0 with no characters in it. Since a zero length read on a normal file indicates that the end of file has been reached the `gets` library function also interprets this as the end of file and stops reading the input. However since it filled the buffer with 5 characters it doesn't return NULL to indicate that it reached end of the file. And since it hasn't actually actually reached end of file, as terminal devices aren't actually files, further calls to `gets` after this will make further calls to `read` which will return any subsequent characters that the user types.

On Windows CTRL-Z is handled much differently. The biggest difference is that it's not treated specially by the operating system at all. When you type `house^Z^Z^M` on Windows only the carriage return character is given special treatment. Just like on Unix, the carriage return makes the typed line available to the program, though in this case a carriage return and a line feed are added to the buffer to mark the end of the line.  So the result is that `ReadFile` function returns a 9 byte long buffer with the 9 characters `house^Z^Z^M^J` in it.

It actually the program itself, specifically the C runtime library, that treats CTRL-Z specially.  In the case of the Microsoft C runtime library when it sees the CTRL-Z character in the buffer returned by `ReadFile` it treats it as an end-of-file marker and ignores everything else after it.  Using the example in the previous paragraph, `gets` ends up calling `ReadFile` to get more input because the fact its seen the CTRL-Z character isn't remembered when reading from the console (or other device) and it hasn't yet seen the end-of-line (which was ignored). If you then press enter again, `gets` will return with the buffer filled with the 7 bytes `house^Z\0` (adding a 0 byte to indicate the end of the string). By default, it does the much same thing when reading from normal files,  if a CTRL-Z character appears in a file, it and everything after it is ignored. This is for backward-compatibility with CP/M which only supported files in lengths that were multiples of 128 and used CTRL-Z to mark where text files really were supposed to end.

Note that both the Unix and Windows behaviours described above are only the normal default handling of user input. The Unix handling of CTRL-D only occurs when reading from a terminal device in canonical mode and it's possible to change the "end-of-file" character to something else. On Windows the operating system never treats CTRL-Z specially, but whether the C runtime library does or not depends on whether the FILE stream being read is in text or binary mode. This is why in portable programs you should always include the character `b` in the mode string when opening binary files (eg. `fopen("foo.gif", "rb")`).

Comment: First of all I want to thank you for your in depth analysis of the different implementations. However I noticed CTRL-Z is handled in a slightly different way on Windows, in particular if I type `house^Z^Z^Z\n` only the second and third "^Z" are ignored.

Comment: This means that `puts(str)` prints on screen the string "house^Z" (where ^Z is printed as a non-ASCII character). My interpretation is that a `getchar()` call inside `gets` returns EOF only if `ReadFile`: a) has no character to read (end of file) b) encounters a `^Z` as the first character in the buffer. If `^Z` is in the middle of the buffer instead it just triggers the closure of the buffer, but then `getchar()` still returns "^Z". PS: I am referring to an implementation of `gets` like the `getS` above by `user3856986`.

Comment: It's actually everything after the first ^Z that's ignored, at least with the Microsoft C runtime library implementation. Other implementations are possible, like the one `user3856986` posted, although that one isn't conforming so I'm not sure if it's actually used in any real C runtime library let alone a Windows one. How exactly ^Z is handled will depend on the implementation and possibly other details the like buffering mode of the stream.

Comment: @Elanigiro I've updated the answer to address the CTRL-Z character appearing in the output on Windows. This actually seems to be change in behaviour, I don't think older versions of the Microsoft CRT would've included the CTRL-Z character.