# How to detect end of input in C++

Tags: c++

I'm stuck with a problem.

```
main()
{
    Node* head = new Node();
    int k;
    deleteAtHead(head);
    while(????)
    {
        if( input is ended )
        {
            printList(head);
            break;
        }
        cin >> k;
        if(k == 1)
        {
            int w;
            cin >> w;
            insertAtTheHead(&head, w);
        }
        if(k == 2)
        {
            int w;
            cin >> w;
            insertAtTheTail(&head, w);
        }
        if(k == 3)
        {
            deleteAtHead(head);
        }
        if(k == 4)
        {
            deleteAtTail(head);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want the while loop to end when end of input is reached, but I don't know what to do.
for example if the input is  `1 13 1 22 2 60 3 1 10`, while loop must be stopped when we reached 10.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `while (cin >> k) {` and get rid of the `if( input is ended ) {}` block completely also remove `cin >> k;` where it is now and finally put `printList(head);` after the loop.

Comment: After that learn what the key for your OS is to signal the end of the input: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41222635/different-behaviour-of-ctrl-d-unix-and-ctrl-z-windows#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=The%20CTRL%2DD%20and%20CTRL,is%20actually%20a%20delimiter%20character.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41222635/different-behaviour-of-ctrl-d-unix-and-ctrl-z-windows#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=The%20CTRL%2DD%20and%20CTRL,is%20actually%20a%20delimiter%20character.)

Comment: Be aware that both suggestions will require you to terminate input to your program in a way that it can't receive any more input if you wanted it for another task later. Alternatively, you could read in the input as a `std::string` using `std::getline()`, and then parse out the numbers from that string such as via `std::istringstream`. That will leave `std::cin` open to receive more input if you want it.